# Android Adapters - Which One To Use?

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I am still unclear about which adapter to use in a situation that doesn't require the basic, SimpleAdapter.  There are BaseAdapters, ArrayAdapters, CustomAdapters, etc.

I would like to make a ListView with a simple layout like seen in the comment section in the Google PlayStore.  A TextView on one side, and an image that pops up a context menu of some sort.

What adapter would I use for this that would work best?

Comment: I can't understand why You shouldn't be using SimpleAdapter. You can define your custom adapter (extending baseAdapter) and layout

Comment: I was under the impression with SimpleAdapter that there are only a couple of pre-defined layouts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case it is easier to use a `SimpleAdapter`. Just provide your custom layout and connect the data with the widgets' id. Something similar to this:

```
List<HashMap<String,String>> datalist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
map.put("text", "some text");
map.put("image",Integer.toString( R.drawable.your_image_to_popup_a_menu ));
datalist.add( map );

String[] from = { "text","image" };
int[] to = { R.id.txt,R.id.img };

SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter( this, datalist, R.layout.your_layout, from, to);
```

Do not forget to identify the layout's TextView  and ImageView as `"@+id/txt"` and `"@+id/img"` respectively.

(If your image is always the same, just set it in the layout and forget linking the `R.id.img` part)